# JavaScript - Call css file/css code from javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi
In JavaScript, how can I do the same function like the code(PHP) below?

```
<?php 
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Chrome') == true) {
  echo "<style>h1 { color: red; }</style>";
}
?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of good answers below, all depending on exactly what you are looking. I think if you clarified your question more it would be easier to pick a right answer. (i.e. why do you need to detect a certain browser? did you instead want to detect a browser feature (like geolocation or local storage?))

Comment: I also see more people moving away from detecting browsers / versions because there are so many that people would like to support and keeping track of all of those features for every browser can get messy. It is better to use feature detection instead. jQuery moved this direction awhile ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if (is_chrome) {
  document.writeln("<style>h1 { color: red; }</style>");
}
```

Source for chrome detection:
http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript

You may want different browser detection using javascript:
http://javascriptly.com/2008/09/javascript-to-detect-google-chrome/

Answer (score 0):

use the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) script to do feature detection for you then modify your CSS code to take advantage of the added classes.

Comment: Is it working for mobile phone such as Android, iPhone and so on?

Comment: Modernizr takes a different approach. It tests to see if the current browser has certain features rather than maintain a database of browsers matched with features. If you are looking to identify the specific browser, Modernizr will not work for you. If you want to take advantage of certain features regardless of the browser, then it works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 )
   document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">h1 { color: red; }</style>");
```

Another variant, shorter

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1 ?
       document.write("<style type=\"text/css\">h1 { color: red; }</style>") : "";
```

Comment: kudos on an exact equivalent, but i cannot find it in me to upvote a really bad practice like navigator useragent detection.

Comment: @nathan you are write. As far as remember browser detection is a little bit uncertain, because it is based on headers, which can be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

On smartphone browser, things are a bit complex as different versions of browser behaves differently to javascript/css. For example android browser doesn't support html5 till android os 2.0 and in later os versions it does support html5 video tag but not audio tag. Similarly there are variations on mobile safari. So the best way is looking at user-agent string and parse it for os versions/platform / os and act accordingly.I wrote a small function to retrieve some info from browser user-agent.

```
var agentInfo=(function(){
  var info={}, 
  ua=navigator.userAgent.split(/[()]/)[1].split(/;/);
  info.platform=ua[0] && ua[0].toLowerCase();
  info.version=ua[2] && ua[2].match(/[0-9._]+/g)[0];
  info.os=ua[2] && (temp=ua[2].match(/[^0-9_.]+/g)[0].toLowerCase()) && (temp=/(windows)|(linux)|(mac)|(iphone)|(android)/.exec(temp)) && temp[0];
  return info;
})();
```

Now based on os/platform/version you can write appropriate css.